# Failed to load resource javascript window.location

Tags: javascript

Trying to validate an age from one form i found this issue on the console of chrome. 
this is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function CalAge() {

     var dd = $("#day").val();
     var mm = $("#month").val();
     var yy = $("#year").val();
     var age = 18;

     var mydate = new Date();
     mydate.setFullYear(yy, mm-1, dd);

     var currdate = new Date();
     currdate.setFullYear(currdate.getFullYear() - age);

     if(dd !=0 || mm !=0 || yy !=0){ //whether one or all values havent been choosen
         if ((currdate - mydate) < 18){
            window.location = "http://www.google.com";
         }
         else{
            alert("more than 18");
        }
     }
     else{
         alert("please register");

     }
   }
</script>
```

i wonder if is something to do with my code, because if i put the url relocation in somewhere else in the code (like on top of the conditions) it works just fine.
any suggestion

Comment: Try `window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";`

Comment: already did and is not working either.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `if ((currdate - mydate) < 18)` isn't evaluating to true.

In your example, `currdate` is the cutoff date for being 18 years old. Your condition should be:

```
if (currdate < mydate) { ... }
```

That is, if someone is born after the cutoff date (i.e., is less than 18 years old), then redirect to Google.

Answer (score -1):

That's a good explanation given to the error... I think you have to replace the `window.location` with something like this: `window.location.assign("http://www.google.com")` and also use only one `else` to alert all your popups! If optional... Good luck!
Oookay! Use this:
`
         function CalAge() {

```
     var dd = $("#day").val();
     var mm = $("#month").val();
     var yy = $("#year").val();
     var age = 18;

     var mydate = new Date();
     mydate.setFullYear(yy, mm-1, dd);

     var currdate = new Date();
     currdate.setFullYear(currdate.getFullYear() - age);

     if(dd !=0 || mm !=0 || yy !=0){ //whether one or all values havent been choosen

     var subit = currdate - mydate;
         if (subit < 18){
            window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
         }
         else{
            alert("more than 18");
        }
     }
     else{
         alert("please register");

     }
   }
</script>`
     thanks good luck
```

Comment: did not work either. you think i should change something else in my code. because is not working at all. Thanks again